Why I am getting this warning while running `npm install -g create-react-app` and how to clear the vulnerabilities?
npm warn deprecated inflight@1.0.6: This module is not supported, and leaks memory. Do not use it. Check out lru-cache if you want a good and tested way to coalesce async requests by a key value, which is much more comprehensive and powerful.
npm warn deprecated fstream-ignore@1.0.5: This package is no longer supported.
npm warn deprecated rimraf@2.7.1: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated uid-number@0.0.6: This package is no longer supported.
npm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated fstream@1.0.12: This package is no longer supported.
npm warn deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.

This is the warning I am getting when I am try to run npm install -g create-react-app
up to date, audited 1545 packages in 3s

262 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

8 vulnerabilities (2 moderate, 6 high)

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.

When I am running the npm install command, its tell that having 8 vulnerabilities
When I am auditing the report, it showing
# npm audit report

nth-check  <2.0.1
Severity: high
Inefficient Regular Expression Complexity in nth-check - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-rp65-9cf3-cjxr
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@3.0.1, which is a breaking change
node_modules/svgo/node_modules/nth-check
  css-select  <=3.1.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of nth-check
  node_modules/svgo/node_modules/css-select
    svgo  1.0.0 - 1.3.2
    Depends on vulnerable versions of css-select
    node_modules/svgo
      @svgr/plugin-svgo  <=5.5.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of svgo
      node_modules/@svgr/plugin-svgo
        @svgr/webpack  4.0.0 - 5.5.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/plugin-svgo
        node_modules/@svgr/webpack
          react-scripts  >=2.1.4
          Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/webpack
          Depends on vulnerable versions of resolve-url-loader
          node_modules/react-scripts

postcss  <8.4.31
Severity: moderate
PostCSS line return parsing error - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-7fh5-64p2-3v2j
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@3.0.1, which is a breaking change
node_modules/resolve-url-loader/node_modules/postcss
  resolve-url-loader  0.0.1-experiment-postcss || 3.0.0-alpha.1 - 4.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/resolve-url-loader

8 vulnerabilities (2 moderate, 6 high)

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

I tried multiple things to figure it out, but couldn't get rid of it. What can I try next?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

CRA is not recommended these days. Use a more modern tool like Vite.

try to disable eslint in .env file:
EXTEND_ESLINT=true
